# Remove duplicates vba

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to have a list where I upload some rows and where it automatically removes the duplicates. Still my code is not working properly. When I add new duplicates it removes them, but not the old ones. I checkd this with a simple countif. In addition the build in remoe duplicate function does not seem to work. Can anyone tell me what is the basis of this problem?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Thanks

| 714287 | OK |
| --- | --- |
| 760202 | OK |
| 731050 | OK |
| 732010 | OK |
| 774310 | OK |
| 733010 | Duplicate |
| 761250 | OK |
| 761510 | Duplicate |
| 760205 | OK |
| 740813 | OK |
| 732003 | OK |
| 732014 | Duplicate |
| 732023 | OK |
| 3301127 | Duplicate |
| 3305015 | OK |
| 3300214 | OK |
| 3301038 | OK |
| 3300210 | Duplicate |
| 3391611 | Duplicate |
| 1006462 | OK |
| 1007338 | Duplicate |
| 732012C | Duplicate |
| 731050R | OK |
| 771330 | OK |
| 761251 | OK |
| 1000002 | OK |
| 761252 | OK |
| 1000001 | OK |
| 3031100 | Duplicate |
| 732073 | OK |
| 732054 | OK |
| 732037 | OK |
| 732099 | OK |
| 752110 | OK |
| 762012 | OK |
| 731000R | OK |
| 732014 | Duplicate |
| 733010 | Duplicate |
| 761510 | Duplicate |
| 3301033 | OK |
| 3301127 | Duplicate |
| 3391611 | Duplicate |
| 1007338 | Duplicate |
| 3300210 | Duplicate |
| 740811 | OK |
| 732012C | Duplicate |
| 1008507 | OK |
| 1016320 | OK |
| 1008065 | OK |
| 1010300 | OK |
| 1007042 | OK |
| 1010922 | OK |
| 3301039 | OK |
| 3301155 | OK |
| 3031100 | Duplicate |

Comment: This question needs data sample.And probably because this is trapped into Worksheet_change, that may a reason too. But your question needs more focus right now

Comment: Try starting the code with Application.EnableEvents = False` and end it with `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: @FaneDuru That doesn't seem to solve it

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I'm not sure if I can upload a data sample cause of company regulations. I'll double check.

Comment: You can upload a data sample that demonstrates the problem. It does not have to be confidential company information.  To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).  Also take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you want removing duplicates only from column A:A? Can you share your workbook? At least picture showing what is before the code run and another one showing it after. Mentioning what duplicates have not been removed. But before that, try checking if events are enabled. Put a break point on the event code line and see if the code stops there when you change something in the sheet.

Comment: I added a table to original post. it's a snapshot of my data.  if I try to run my code on this data (without second column). It does not change a thing. It also does not seem to pasue at breakpoint. Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove Column Duplicates

- The issue you (we) are encountering is probably due to the first column containing mixed data: numbers and strings. Manually you could do something like adding another column and using the formula `=TEXT(A1,"#")` and then copy it back and do the remove duplicates. I tried for a while to do it in VBA using `RemoveDuplicates`, but couldn't get it to work. An idea might be to write the formula to another worksheet (workbook) and then process it there and then copy it back... it all becomes rather messy.
- So I rather created a different solution consisting of multiple procedures that do cover some ridiculous scenarios but might come in handy in some other projects of yours.
- The main procedure is `removeColumnDupes` which you call from the `Worksheet Change` event code or from the two other preceding small procedures. It will call the remaining procedures when necessary. Copy all of it to the appropriate modules.
- In the worksheet, nothing will happen until you change a value in column `A`. If you don't want to change anything just select one of the cells and click on the `Formula Bar` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is also considered a change. Now the duplicates have been removed and you cannot enter a duplicate in column `A`.
- If you don't want to use the event, you can uncomment the `Exit Sub` at the beginning of it or uncomment or delete it. Then you can use `removeColumnDupesTEST`. Note that if you haven't disabled the event solution, this will cause the `removeDupes` procedure to always run three times: once for itself (...TEST), once for writing the data, and once for clearing the contents.
- The `removeColumnDupesSelection` procedure may come in handy when you want to select any cell and remove the duplicates from it to the bottom-most unoccupied cell.
- Note when using this event, you have to be careful that it won't get retriggered again and again and 'crash' `Excel`. This is done by disabling events. See this in the event procedure.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1` (the name not in parentheses in `VBE Project Explorer`)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Exit Sub ' Uncomment if you don't want to run it.
    Const ProcName As String = "Worksheet_Change"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Const FirstCell As String = "A2"
    Dim cel As Range: Set cel = Range(FirstCell)
    If Not Intersect(Columns(cel.Column), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        removeColumnDupes cel
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

' Select the first cell in a column in which you want to remove dupes and run.
Sub removeColumnDupesSelection()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        removeColumnDupes Selection.Cells(1)
    End If
End Sub

' Run in a column.
Sub removeColumnDupesTEST()
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    removeColumnDupes Range(FirstCellAddress)
End Sub

' Main Procedure
Sub removeColumnDupes( _
        FirstCellRange As Range, _
        Optional ByVal clearContentsBelow As Boolean = True)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = refColumn(FirstCellRange)
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = getColumn(rg)
    Data = getUniqueData(Data)
    writeColumnData FirstCellRange, Data, clearContentsBelow
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a worksheet column, creates a reference to the range
'               from a given cell 'FirstCellRange' to the bottom-most
'               unoccupied cell i.e. all cells below the latter are empty
'               (="", ="'"... are not included).
'                If `NonBlankInsteadOfNonEmpty` is 'True', the bottom-most cell,
'               whose contents have a length of greater than 0, is condsidered
'               as the bottom-most unoccupied cell i.e. all cells below
'               the latter are blank ('Empty', ="", ="'"...).
' Remarks:      Although 'FirstCellRange' can be a range of any size,
'               only its first cell will be considered.
' Limitations:  If the worksheet contains filtered rows, both options may fail.
'               If it contains hidden rows, then only 'NonBlank' may fail.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function refColumn( _
    FirstCellRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal NonBlankInsteadOfNonEmpty As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "refColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then
        With FirstCellRange.Cells(1)
            Dim cLookIn As XlFindLookIn
            If NonBlankInsteadOfNonEmpty Then
                cLookIn = xlValues
            Else
                cLookIn = xlFormulas
            End If
            Dim cel As Range
            Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , cLookIn, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                Set refColumn = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values from a column ('ColumnNumber')
'               of a range ('rg') to a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getColumn( _
    rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal doTranspose As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "getColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        If ColumnNumber > 0 And ColumnNumber <= rg.Columns.Count Then
            With rg.Columns(ColumnNumber)
                Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
                Dim Result As Variant
                If rCount > 1 Then
                    If doTranspose Then
                        Dim Data As Variant: Data = .Value
                        ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To rCount)
                        Dim r As Long
                        For r = 1 To rCount
                            Result(1, r) = Data(r, 1)
                        Next r
                        getColumn = Result
                    Else
                        getColumn = .Value
                    End If
                Else
                    ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Result(1, 1) = .Value
                    getColumn = Result
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the unique values from a 2D array
'               to a 2D one-based array, excluding error and blank values.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getUniqueData( _
    Data As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal Order As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows, _
    Optional ByVal Direction As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional ByVal CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare, _
    Optional ByVal doTranspose As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "getUniqueData"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not IsEmpty(Data) Then
        Dim Limits(1 To 4) As Long
        Limits(1) = LBound(Data, 1): Limits(2) = UBound(Data, 1)
        Limits(3) = LBound(Data, 2): Limits(4) = UBound(Data, 2)
        Dim r1 As Long: r1 = Limits(Direction + 2 * (Order - 1))
        Dim r2 As Long: r2 = Limits(3 - Direction + 2 * (Order - 1))
        Dim c1 As Long: c1 = Limits(Direction + 2 * (2 - Order))
        Dim c2 As Long: c2 = Limits(3 - Direction + 2 * (2 - Order))
        Dim st1 As Long: st1 = 3 - 2 * Direction
        Dim st2 As Long: st2 = 3 - 2 * Direction
        Dim d1 As Long: d1 = 2 - Direction ' 2-1=1,2-2=0
        Dim d2 As Long: d2 = Direction - 1 ' 1-1=0,2-1=1
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim r As Long
        Dim c As Long
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            .CompareMode = CompareMethod
            For r = r1 To r2 Step st1
                For c = c1 To c2 Step st2
                    Key = Data(r * d1 + c * d2, r * d2 + c * d1)
                    If Not IsError(Key) Then
                        If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                            .Item(Key) = Empty
                        End If
                    End If
                Next c
            Next r
            Dim uCount As Long: uCount = .Count
            If uCount > 0 Then
                Dim Result As Variant
                If doTranspose Then
                    ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To uCount)
                    c = 0
                    For Each Key In .Keys
                        c = c + 1
                        Result(1, c) = Key
                    Next Key
                Else
                    ReDim Result(1 To uCount, 1 To 1)
                    r = 0
                    For Each Key In .Keys
                        r = r + 1
                        Result(r, 1) = Key
                    Next Key
                End If
                getUniqueData = Result
            End If
        End With
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values of the first column of a given 2D one-based
'               array to a worksheet column starting from
'               a given cell 'FirstCellRange'.
'               Optionally (by default) it previously clears the contents
'               below the resulting data.
' Remarks:      Although 'FirstCellRange' can be a range of any size,
'               only its first cell will be considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub writeColumnData( _
        FirstCellRange As Range, _
        ByVal Data As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal clearContentsBelow As Boolean = True)
    Const ProcName As String = "writeColumnData"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Data) Then
            With FirstCellRange.Cells(1)
                Dim dCount As Long: dCount = UBound(Data, 1)
                .Resize(dCount, 1).Value = Data
                If clearContentsBelow Then
                    .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - dCount + 1) _
                        .Offset(dCount).ClearContents
                End If
                Debug.Print .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - dCount + 1) _
                    .Offset(dCount).Address, .Resize(UBound(Data, 1), 1).Address
            End With
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```